# Django REST API and Nuxt.js - (CORS error in Nuxt)

Tags: python, django, cors, nuxt.js

I can access my Django REST api using Postman however when I run it on Nuxt, I get the "has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Let me know which parts of my code you would like to see and I will be happy to share.

Here is my settings.py file

```
DEBUG = True

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'core',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
            'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', # add this
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000'

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely the issue from the backend side, I mean Django.

So the attribute values should look like this on Django side.
`CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS=True`

Once you set the `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS` value, you also need to set the values for `ALLOWED_HOSTS`.
For instance `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']`

Please take a look at the below links.

https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/

https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-fix-django-cors-error

Comment: I tried that now. See code above. This is my exact error:(index):1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/leagues' from origin 'http://192.168.0.11:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/leagues net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: please try to use `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`

Comment: oh wow ....that worked! Nice! Thanks web-sudo. I think I will try to host and run django on heroku now and see if I can still access from Nuxt.

Comment: Hi Web-sudo. I am running into a few more issues while trying to learn using the Django-rest framework tutorial, found here https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis/. Do you think you could help me out? What is the best way to reach you?

Comment: please ping me on skype. hollywood.itdev@gmail.com